# Entity Framework Map one table to another others two different tables depends column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

**Table [Note]**

Id int 
Description nvarchar(255)
ClassName nvarchar(50)
ClassId int

**Table [User]**

Id int
FullName nvarchar(255)
Enable bit
Address nvarchar(255)
Email nvarchar(255)

**Table [Client]**

Id int
CompanyName nvarchar(255)
PhoneNumber nvarchar(255)
Address nvarchar(255)
Email nvarchar(255)

**The following classes:**

```
public class User{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public bool Enable { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
}



public class Client{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
   public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
}


public class Note{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string ClassName { get; set; }
   public int ClassId { get; set; }

   public virtual User { get; set; } <-- Populate depending on the ClassName and ClassId fields
   public virtual Client { get; set; } <-- Populate depending on the ClassName and ClassId fields
}
```

**Table NOTE example**

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦
║ id ║ Description ║ ClassName ║ ClassId ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬
║ 1  ║Test Note 1  ║ Client    ║ 2544    ║ 
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬
║ 2  ║Test Note 2  ║ User      ║ 25      ║ 
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬
║ 3  ║Test Note 3  ║ Client    ║ 2578    ║ 
╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩
```

Note that in the note class there are two objects

**public virtual User { get; set; }**
  **public virtual Client { get; set; }**

What I need to do is to map in the table **Note** one of the two tables  **User** or **Client**, depending on the **ClassName** field in the database. So, the entity should know in which table to find the information. 
If in the **ClassName** field is **"Client"** it will populate the **Client** object if it is **"User"** it should populate the **User** object.

Is it possible to do this using Entity Framework?